# Intuition behind Picard's Thorem requiring f to be Lipschitz in the *second* variable (rather than the first variable)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

These are the statements of Picard's Theorem I've been taught

> Let $f:R\to\mathbb R$ be a function defined on the rectangle $R:= \{(x,y):|x-a|\leq h, |y-b|\leq k\}$ which satisfies
>
> 1. f is continuous in R with bound M and $Mh\leq k$
> 2. f satisfies a Lipschitz condition in R
>    ie. $\exists L>0:|f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)| \leq L|y_1-y_2| \  \forall x\in [a-h,a+h], \forall y_1,y_2 \in [b-k,b+k]$
>
> Then the IVP $y'(x)=f(x,y(x))$ with $y(a)=b$ has a unique solution y on the interval [a-h,a+h]

> Suppose that $f:R\to\mathbb R$ is a continuous function on an unbounded rectangle $R = [c,d] \times \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies a global Lipschitz condition on R ie. $\exists L>0:|f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)| \leq L|y_1-y_2| \  \forall x\in [a-h,a+h], \forall y_1,y_2 \in \mathbb R$. Then for any $a\in[c,d]$ and any $b\in\mathbb R$ the IVP has a unique solution that is defined on all of [c,d]

As in the subject, I don't think I understand the intuition about why the Lipschitz condition is placed on the second variable rather than the first. I can follow the algebra but don't fully understand why it works. Further to this, in the global existence version of Picard's theorem, why do we look for a global Lipschitz condition in the second variable when we want a global solution for all x

Answer (score 1):

The points that you iterate over in the Picard iteration are functions, the vector space is the space of continuous functions. Thus in comparing points in this function space, you only compare values at the same $x$ coordinate.

Thus also the contraction factor of the Picard iterator uses only the differences of values with same $x$ "index". Thus it is sufficient to have a Lipschitz constant only in $y$ direction.

---

This changes if you want to do more, like compare solutions with initial conditions at different $x$ coordinates. Or if you explore the accuracy of numerical methods, where a finite number of values of the ODE function in the numerical step are compared to all values of the ODE function at the exact solution over the step interval.